# Error importing RandomForestClassifier form sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, random-forest

When I try to run the imports chunk of code from a notebook I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10532/2760964086.py in <module>
----> 1 from StudyProcess import *
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 from sklearn.cluster import SpectralBiclustering

~StudyProcess.py in <module>
     10 import os
     11 from WordEmbeding import WordEmbedding
---> 12 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
     13 from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor
     14 from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\__init__.py in <module>
     16 from ._weight_boosting import AdaBoostClassifier
     17 from ._weight_boosting import AdaBoostRegressor
---> 18 from ._gb import GradientBoostingClassifier
     19 from ._gb import GradientBoostingRegressor
     20 from ._voting import VotingClassifier

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_gb.py in <module>
     31 from ..base import is_classifier
     32 
---> 33 from ._gradient_boosting import predict_stages
     34 from ._gradient_boosting import predict_stage
     35 from ._gradient_boosting import _random_sample_mask

sklearn\ensemble\_gradient_boosting.pyx in init sklearn.ensemble._gradient_boosting()

ValueError: sklearn.tree._tree.TreeBuilder size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 80 from C header, got 72 from PyObject
```

Can somebody help me? I am using the latest versions of python and scykit-learn.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

Should fix it.